# vsftpd on raspberry pi doesn't chroot users

Tags: linux, debian, ftp, raspberry-pi, vsftpd

I'm attempting to run an FTP server on a raspberry pi, and after a lot of struggle I finally made it work, however for some reason the server doesn't place users into a chroot jail, and everyone can access all files on the device.
Strange is that I did set chroot_local_user to YES, but it doesn't work as I said. Any ideas?

```
# Example config fil /etc/vsftpd.conf
#
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/$USER/ftp
```

Comment: I have the directory set up, the owner is root and write perimissions are disabled for all users, and it was done before I started vsftpd (tried reboot as well with no effect)

Comment: See if this helps you any just in case: http://serverfault.com/questions/544850/create-new-vsftpd-user-and-lock-to-specify-home-login-directory/544892#544892

Comment: Okay something REALLY weird is going on. I can connect to the ftp server even if the service vsftpd is disabled! I have a fresh install of raspbian and I didn't use any other ftp servers.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I was connecting to a different ftp server all along (probably the stock sftp server?). I made vsftpd run on a different port and now it works fine (does chroot users)